# Moving Logs into a Kubernetes Cluster

Tags: kubernetes, logging

I have Grafana running inside a Kubernetes Cluster and i want to push logs from outside of Kubernetes (apps not running in K8s/DB's etc) into kubernetes so i can view them inside the Grafana cluster. What's the best way of doing this?

Comment: did you tried `promtail` ?

Answer (score 0):

So Grafana is a GUI for reporting on data stored in other databases. It sounds like you are capturing metrics from the cluster and this data is stored in another database. If you are running Prometheus this is the database for Grafana's time-series data. You also may end up running long-term storage systems like Thanos in the future for that data to keep it over time depending on the volume of data.

Back to logging... Similarly to use Grafana for logs you'll need to implement some kind of logging database. The most popular is the formerly open-source ELK (ElasticSearch, Logstash, Kibana) stack. You can now use OpenSearch which is an open-source version of ElasticSearch and Kibana. Most K8S distributions come with Fluentd which replaces logstash for sending data. You can also install Fluentd or Fluentbit on any host to send data to this stack. You'll find that Grafana is not the best for log analysis, so most people use Kibana (OpenSearch Dashboards). However you can use Grafana as well, it's just painful IMO.

Another option if you don't want to run ELK is using Grafana Loki, which is another open-source database for logging. It's a lot more simple, but also more limited as to how you can query the logs due to the way it indexes. It works nicely with Grafana, but once again this is not a full-text indexing technology so it will be a bit limited.

Hope this is helpful, let me know if you have questions!